# Changing hostname and domain joining fine; but when specifying OU

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory, ou, organizational-unit

So when I run the following script it works as expected

```
$newname = Read-Host 'Desired hostname'
$user = Read-Host 'Domain admin username'
$cpc = hostname.exe
Add-Computer -DomainName DOMAIN.CO.UK -ComputerName $cpc -NewName $newname -Credential domain\$user
pause
```

However when I then attempt to add `-OUPath "OU=ourou,OU=ourou,DC=domain,DC=co,DC=uk"` like so:

```
$newname = Read-Host 'Desired hostname'
$user = Read-Host 'Domain admin username'
$cpc = hostname.exe
Add-Computer -DomainName DOMAIN.CO.UK -ComputerName $cpc -NewName $newname -Credential domain\$user -OUPath "OU=Workstations,OU=Windows 10,DC=domain,DC=co,DC=uk"
pause
```

The script breaks, returning:

> failed to join domain from its current workgroup... the system cannot find the file specified

Any ideas?

Here's the AD layout, in case I'm making a silly mistake:

[image: AD OU structure]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone runs in to the same problem, I've now figured out that I was in fact making a silly mistake.

the -OUPath command works backwards through OU trees. So in my example, I wanted to reference the OU: domain.co.uk\Workstations\Windows 10

Originally my code was: `-OUPath "OU=Workstations,OU=Windows 10,DC=domain,DC=co,DC=uk"`

The code I needed was: `-OUPath "OU=Windows 10,OU=Workstations,DC=domain,DC=co,DC=uk"`

Hopefully I've explained that well enough.

Comment: Thanks for adding in your answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped me figure it out!